# Call relaying via GOIP with callee number

Tags: asterisk, voip, gsm

I am working with GoIP16. How I can acheive this functionality with GOIP.

I am calling a number, my call is relayed with GoIP gateway. But the phone number displayed on receiver is of Gateway. I want it to be the callee i-e mine number. Can it be acheived with GOIP. If yes then how and if no what else can be done.

Answer (score 0):

In any GSM network number binded to SIM card. So no, there are no any way change CALLERID number without help of GSM provider.

If you want option to change CID, you need digital connection and that option have be in contract.

Comment: What is meant by digital connection?

Comment: SIP, BRI, isdn E1/t1 or other. Most low cost gsm gates(including goip) is analog gateways - it just read ANALOG output of gsm phone module(like read speaker/write to mic).